# Correct use of multiple providers to render captions for audio using Riverpod and Flutter

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I'm new to riverpod and have been using it to make an app that displays captions along with a voiceover that narrates that text. My goal is to have each word in the sentence change color as the narration reaches the word. I've already determined the timings for each word, so I know when they are spoken in the audio recording.

An example paragraph that shows the currently spoken word might look like:

> The cat in **the** hat

I've setup some providers like this:

```dart
final voiceoverAudioPlayerProvider = Provider((ref) {
  return AudioPlayer();
});
```

The voiceoverTextNotifier makes the API request for the voiceover text, audio file URL and text/narration sync data and sets it to a state value. It also handles playing and stopping the audio once the API response arrives.

```dart
final voiceoverTextProvider = StateNotifierProvider((ref) {
  final voiceoverTextRepository = ref.watch(voiceoverTextRepositoryProvider);


  return voiceoverTextNotifier(
      voiceoverTextRepository: voiceoverTextRepository,
      voiceoverAudioPlayer: voiceoverAudioPlayer);
});
```

The widget looks something like this:

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final voiceoverTextState = ref.watch(voiceoverTextProvider);

    var words = <Widget>[];

    voiceoverTextState.when(
        data: (voiceoverText) {
          for (int i = 0; i < voiceoverText.paragraph.length; i++) {
            // Set text color here to `Colors.red`?
            words.add(Text(voiceoverText.paragraph[i].text, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)))
          }
          
        },
        ...

   return Wrap(children: words);
 }
```

The audioplayer provides a stream of position updates `audioPlayer.onAudioPositionChanged` which give me the duration. I can use that duration + the sync data that comes with each word to determine which word should show up.

I'm not sure where/how I should be listening to the stream and comparing it to the caption data. From what I've read, it doesn't make sense to put it in the widget.

I've tried a few different approaches but haven't been able to make the text color change happen with the right performance. In one case, it notices when the provider changes, but only every few seconds, so skips words. I don't think I'm using the provider correctly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Flutter and Riverpod are not the culprit. The `audioplayers` package documentation indicates that the stream of position events gives data every 200 milliseconds, which is why I'm seeing things jump. I'm going to look at alternate packages for audio playback.